# Allocating a 2d Array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

My aim is to allocate a 2d array with only using 1 line for efficiency. Since my prof is expecting it to be efficient. 
the code gives me an error saying that it can't convert from void* to int.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define NUMOFCOL 4

int **addtwoarr(int (*A)[NUMOFCOL], int (*B)[NUMOFCOL]);

int main(void){
    int firstarr[4][4]={{1,1,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1}},
        secondarr[4][4]={{1,1,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1},
                        {1,1,1,1}}, **receiver;
    receiver = addtwoarr(firstarr, secondarr);
    printf("%d", receiver[3][3]);
}

int **addtwoarr(int (*A)[NUMOFCOL], int (*B)[NUMOFCOL]){
    int col, row, **arr;
    (*arr)[NUMOFCOL] = malloc(NUMOFCOL * sizeof(*arr)); /*this line in particular gives the error */
    for(row=0; row<NUMOFCOL; row++){
        for(col=0;col<NUMOFCOL; arr[row][col]=A[row][col]+B[row][col], col++){}
    }
    return arr;
}
```

The allocation happens in the addtwoarr function which is where the error occurs.

Comment: `(*arr)[NUMOFCOL] = ...` ?? Well, `arr` had better point to something before that line is reached. The rest looks like a guess.

Comment: What about static initialization? Requires no runtime at all.

Comment: Ahh. I've seen people do int (*m)[CCOLS] = malloc(cRows * sizeof(*m));
but I just can't get that part right.

Comment: i'm trying to replicate that because it mallocs a 2d array and it only consumes one line. The other ways of allocating requires a loop.

Comment: The return value is equally important. `int **arr` is a pointer to an `int` pointer; not a pointer to an array. I.e. that's wrong as well.

Comment: Ahhh okay. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seriously don't recommend this, as there are a ton of assumptions in your code about top-end sizing. But if you really want to do it, the rather cryptic syntax for returning pointers to fixed length arrays in C looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMOFCOL 4

int (*addtwoarr(int A[][NUMOFCOL], int B[][NUMOFCOL]))[NUMOFCOL];

int main(void)
{
    int firstarr[][NUMOFCOL] = {
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1}},

    secondarr[][NUMOFCOL] = {
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1}};

    int (*receiver)[NUMOFCOL] =  addtwoarr(firstarr, secondarr);
    printf("%d\n", receiver[3][3]);
    free(receiver);
}

int (*addtwoarr(int A[][NUMOFCOL], int B[][NUMOFCOL]))[NUMOFCOL]
{
    int col, row;
    int (*arr)[NUMOFCOL] = malloc(NUMOFCOL * sizeof(*arr));
    for(row=0; row<NUMOFCOL; row++){
        for(col=0;col<NUMOFCOL; arr[row][col]=A[row][col]+B[row][col], col++);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

**Output**

```
2
```

Best of luck.

Comment: it's giving me an error
"23 55 C:\Fraps\Addmatrix.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int (*)[4]' [-fpermissive]"
"27 9 C:\Fraps\Addmatrix.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[4]' to 'int**' in return". (i'm using dev-c since my prof tells me to use it.)
but thanks! it's an error on my part. I really forgot about freeing it also.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. [Runs correctly **here**](http://ideone.com/esKGpS). And since there isn't a single solitary `int **` in the code I posted, perhaps consider *everything* rather than just parts of it. Notice the return value type has changed as well (it had to) in both the prototype and the implementation. And of course, make sure you're compiling as C, and not C++.

Comment: Oh my! It does run correctly. I didn't run it as C. Sorry. the code runs perfectly. But may I ask if there's another way of making it run without having
int (*addtwoarr(int A[][NUMOFCOL], int B[][NUMOFCOL]))[NUMOFCOL]
as the parameter.

Comment: Not really. You could always return `void *`, but I recommend that even less. I'm going to omit describing allocating a ganged-together pointer array with a linear data sequence in the interest of sanity (trust me, you don't wanna do it that way either).

Comment: Ahh, okay. But in terms of allocating a 2d array. What method would be the best? Would there be a method without using for loops? And thanks for answering my question.

Comment: "best" is in the eye of the beholder. Everything has advantage and disadvantage to some extent. What I showed you has the advantage of being a single, simple allocation at the expense of limited flexibility (only things `NUMOFCOL` wide allowed) and arguably cryptic syntax. But it is a true array of arrays. A pointer-array approach (`type **`) allows variant row lengths, fast row insertions, etc, but lots more pointer management. It really depends on your situation. And glad it helped.

Comment: Ahh alright. I guess it depends on the situation. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joshua: "*invalid conversion from 'void *' to 'int ()[4]' [-fpermissive]" "27 9 C:\Fraps\Addmatrix.cpp*" Using a C++ compiler to compile code which is meant to be C code probably isn't a good idea.